# How do you configure an "ASCII" transfer mode using FTP with the NSStream classes.

Tags: ios, ftp

My App uses the NSStream classes to FTP a file from the iPhone to a server. The file is transferred but the contents are corrupted. The FTP server logs indicate that the transfer type used was "image" where the original file is of type "ASCII". I searched the KCFStreamProperty list but there seems to be no applicable property to set to control the transfer type.

I experimented with the Apple provided SimpleFTP application. It transfers up images. Changing to transfer an ASCII text file causes the same corruption issue.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sending data that originated in an NSString?  If so, you are probably sending Unicode data (multi bytes per character) you may need to encode the string with UTF8 or ASCII - sorry I am can't find the exact method right now, but this may give you a clue

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I an actually transferring an xml file opened with a NSSTream class and using an 8 bit unsigned integer buffer to transfer between streams. Apple has told me that the NSStream ftp only supports image (binary) transfer mode, so I need to look after the conversion of the file from a IOS format to a Windows format. Not sure what that is yet.

Comment: Can you use something to get a hex dump of the file before and after transmission and see what is happening. ASCII mode modifies new line characters so sending a binary file in ASCII mode is bad, but sending XML in image mode should be fine